# How do I define a property to read an attribute from, without instantionating an object?

Tags: c#

Suppose I have:

```
class Person
{
[ColumnAttribute("ID"]
    public int Id;
[ColumnAttribute("Name"]
public string Name;
[ColumnAttribute("DateOfBirth"]
    public date BirthDate;
}
```

I want to read the attribute on some property but without instantionating the Person object. Say for example I want to read the attribute defined on Name property.But I want it to be like that ReadAttribute(Person.Name) without creating an object.

Why do I want that? because this Person object is a Entity object for a framework I am creating, and I want to be able to define the column on which I want to sort the return from the DAL Layer.

I don't want to pass strings because that way the string will get out of sync when I change the database and so on.

So is this possible? The function of the dal is Person.GetAllByAge(int Age, /*somehow here I want to define the sorting*/)
If there is another way to fix this problem I will be happy to hear it. I was thinking of using expression tree maybe, but I am stuck there too.
thanks

### Edit:

thank you all for answearing but the question is not about reading attributes.
i want when calling the dal to call something like that
Dal.Person.GetAllByAge(25, BirthDate)
this will return all the persons which are 25 years old sorted by name
this can be done currently by calling
Dal.Person.GetAllByAge(25, "DateOfBirth")
thanks

Comment: I think the part that threw us off was the first part of the question where you said, "I want to read the attribute on some property but without instantiating the Person object".

Comment: yeah well its hard to explain what i want realy. but i think the example in the edit show it.

Comment: how about using `dynamic` keyword here.. i don't have exact answer but someone might know the implementation

Comment: I noticed you've said "if I change the Column name in the Database then this will fail at runtime". I would hope you weren't in the habit of changing your database structure this way.

Comment: @Shekhar_Pro: i would prefer not to use dynamic at all :)

Comment: @Matthew Abbott: unfortunally the world is not perfect and changes do happen no matter how we tried. and the problem is not with the change , hte problem is being able to detect it at build time instead of runtime. :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I define a property to read an attribute from, without instantionating an object?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5666032/how-do-i-define-a-property-to-read-an-attribute-from-without-instantionating-an)

Comment: @meagar: your comment means that you didnt read the text at the top of the question, besides the question you are referening to is already marked as a duplicate.

Comment: @Karim Welcome to Stack Overflow. The comment you are referring to was automatically inserted by the system when I flagged the other question as a duplicate of this one. When the questions were merged, my comment was carried over.

Comment: @meagar: this is strange because the date of the comment is new , after the merger that is :) anyway thanks for clarification :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In addition to [Pete M's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5666032/how-do-i-define-a-property-to-read-an-attribute-from-without-instantionating-an/5666236#5666236) you could pass the `Func<T1,T2>` used in `IEnumerable<T>.OrderBy` into your method, and order within your method

```
public IEnumerable<Person> GetAllByAge<T>(int age, Func<Person,T> orderBy)
{
   var people = ... (get your collection of 'age' aged people here)
   return people.OrderBy(orderBy);
}
```

Usage would then be `Dal.Person.GetAllByAge(25,p => p.BirthDate)`

Comment: i will take a look into your answer , will need to try it first :) but i think its the most correct one to what i need. but i think that the lamda should be an expression query.

Answer (score 1):

Yep, I defined an extension method, to make it a bit easier, so i can just call `typeof(Person).GetAttributes<CollumnAttribute>()`:

```
        /// <summary>
    /// Loads the configuration from assembly attributes
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T">The type of the custom attribute to find.</typeparam>
    /// <param name="typeWithAttributes">The calling assembly to search.</param>
    /// <returns>An enumeration of attributes of type T that were found.</returns>
    public static IEnumerable<T> GetAttributes<T>(this Type typeWithAttributes)
        where T : Attribute
    {
        // Try to find the configuration attribute for the default logger if it exists
        object[] configAttributes = Attribute.GetCustomAttributes(typeWithAttributes,
            typeof(T), false);

        // get just the first one
        if (configAttributes != null && configAttributes.Length > 0)
        {
            foreach (T attribute in configAttributes)
            {
                yield return attribute;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Okay, I see what you're saying now after your edit.  Let me think on that.

Answer (score 1):

Is there a specific reason to force ordering on the `GetAllByAge()` method itself?  Why not just sort it once you get it back?  Does the order by logic need to happen server side?  I would return a `List<Person>` (which you mentioned doing yourself) and use LINQ to order the set as needed, unless I had a really good reason not to:

```
Dal.Person.GetAllByAge(25).OrderBy(p => p.BirthDate);
```

Comment: +1. Good answer. The OP can combine this into his method as per my answer.

Comment: the only reason why it should be server side because sometimes i would only return the top 1000 records and so sorting client side will return invalid data

Comment: Fair enough.  @Jamiec has the solution for you in that case.  Have you considered looking at L2S or EF?  You would get a lot of the syntax/semantics you're after for "free".

Comment: yeah i looked at both L2S and EF4 and i dont like what they offer. i believe that writing SQL is the best way to do things instead of figuring out why this SQL is generated and so on :)

Answer (score 0):

This is definitely doable without instantiating a `Person` object.  You'll want to use Reflection to access the attribute, specifically the `GetCustomAttributes` method.

[Here's an article for reference.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z919e8tw.aspx)

Your end result may end up looking something like this:

```
System.Attribute[] attrs = System.Attribute.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(Person));  // Reflection.
```

Comment: This doesn't really address your second question, which is a bit unclear yet.  Maybe you would want to ask a separate question for that.

Comment: my problem is not reading the attribute but how can i pass the property i want the attribute to be read in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

Attributes don't allow lambdas as arguments, so `p => p.BirthDate` unfortunately isn't possible. In a similar scenario [I used enums to link things together](http://whathecode.wordpress.com/2010/11/15/viewmodel-property-and-command-factory/).

This worked just fine for my purposes, but still results in some code duplication (being the enum declaration). This does however solve the problem of string literals, and you can now safely refactor your code.

Comment: well i know about enums but i dont want to duplicate code. i am trying to use the DRY principal :)

Comment: @Karim: Well in my scenario it was the cleanest solution, but in your case, Jamiec's answer is definitely better. ;p

Comment: its a good solutions indeed but the main problem is duplication of code. and also its the easiest to implement and understand and i think there wont be any performance problems too :)