# How do I define a property to read an attribute from, without instantionating an object?

Tags: c#

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I define a property to read an attribute from, without instantionating an object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5654853/how-do-i-define-a-property-to-read-an-attribute-from-without-instantionating-an)

Suppose I have:

```
class Person
{
    [ColumnAttribute("ID")]
    public int Id;
    [ColumnAttribute("Name")]
    public string Name;
    [ColumnAttribute("DateOfBirth")]
    public date BirthDate;
}
```

I have a DAL which which have a method that will return a List of Person objects.
Suppose that method is defined as:

```
Person.GetAllByAge(int Age, ??? SortBy)
```

This method will return a list of Persons that have a given age and they will be sorted by the `SortBy` parameter which i defined as `???` because I don't know what kind of type it should be.

One possible example is that this function is defined as:

```
Dal.Person.GetAllByAge(int Age, string SortBy)
```

so an example usage would be:

```
Dal.Person.GetAllByAge(25, "DateOfBirth")
```

But this definition is not strongly typed and if I change the Column name in the Database then this will fail at runtime.

How can I change this to take a property on which to sort instead of it being a string?

For example a usage like this would be very nice:

```
Dal.Person.GetAllByAge(25, BirthDate)
```

or

```
Dal.Person.GetAllByAge(25, p=>p.BirthDate)
```

where `BirthDate` is the name of the property to sort on.